# Set Breakpoint On Code Not Line

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, firebug, microsoft-edge, firefox-developer-tools

I am wondering if there is a way to set a breakpoint on a piece of code, not just on a line of code, in any browser. I am trying to debug some JavaScript and it is quite annoying to have a breakpoint break at the wrong line because I've had to add or delete a line above the breakpoint. So I find that I'm often having to move breakpoints after a code edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`debugger` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) was introduced in ECMAScript 5.1.

> The debugger statement invokes any available debugging functionality, such as setting a breakpoint. If no debugging functionality is available, this statement has no effect.

```
console.log("Before breakpoint");
debugger;
console.log("After breakpoint");
```

Comment: I'm aware of this statement, but it forces the break. It can't be conditional, and it can't be turned off while the code is running. I'm hoping for something that is browser-based.

Comment: @cjbarth what do you mean "can't be conditional" - it's normal JS code, just do `if (variable == "whatever") debugger`. You can even have a property attached to `window` to enable disable debugging, so your condition would look like `if (window.debugMode && condition) debugger`

Comment: @vlaz That is a good idea to use `window.debugMode`. I just wish that browsers could note the context of the code that I set a breakpoint on and keep track of that. Then I wouldn't have to clean up these `debugger` statements after I'm done debugging.

Comment: @cjbarth unfortunately, I've not seen this. `debugger` statements are the only thing I know of that allows you to break on specific place in the code, rather than a line number.